# I can't manage my iTunes subscriptions

Tags: itunes, bug

When I try to upgrade or otherwise manage my iTunes subscriptions, I'm told I need to verify my payment information and am taken to my account screen, an when I then attempt to submit that screen (with "Done") I get a garbled popup:

[image]

Choosing "Buy" just returns to the account screen where I reman stuck and am presented with the same dialog, along with a warning at the top of the account screen:

[image]

Comment: That’s a typical server side / network corruption / cached data error. Does this persist for a couple hours, after a restart or on an entirely different network provider?

Comment: I can do it from iTunes on macOS, just not from iOS.

Comment: It's tough to tell if that template language is cached and you need to sign out of the account and back in or if it's just that one device is connecting to a server that's broken and the other is not. Great image - I usually don't have to do anything except wait to resolve it, but you can poke at things one at a time until you find out if it's anything you control.

Comment: What if you try this from a Mac or PC and the web browser of your choice?